# Select bucket with size N fast in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Please consider following code snippet. How fast I can do this with PostgreSQL?

```
create table target
(
    id bigserial not null primary key,
    my_id bigint,
);

select id
  from (select id
             , count(*) over (partition by my_id) cnt
          from target) t1
 where cnt = 2;
```

I think `index on target(my_id)` should be represented as dictionary of buckets `(my_id) => list of ids`. Would it be possible to *index this index* by size of bucket, so I can quickly retrieve buckets with particular size?

Comment: Are you looking for `width_bucket()`? Unrelated, but: `identity` is a keyword, you should not use it as a column name

Comment: Thanks for `identity`, I've fixed code snippet. I think `width_bucket` is different, cannot see how to apply it here.

Comment: Then what exactly is your question?

Comment: It's about index buckets.

Comment: Are you looking for [brin](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/brin-intro.html) indexes?

Comment: `some sort of dictionary of buckets structure (my_id) => list of ids.` That is not how aggregation works. After aggregation the `id` s have disappeared, (but each one has attributed a +1 to the count) If you want the actual id's, you'll need to remerge the aggregate *sub query* to the original table. `(subquery here ) agg JOIN target t2 ON t2.my_id =aggr.my_id`

Comment: That was related to the index, not query. Thanks for pointing this out. I've fixed description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No index will help you with this query, it has to scan the whole table.

You could consider a materialized view over the aggregate; that could be indexed. But it will not contain the latest data and has to be refreshed periodically.